# Groovy: Is there a constructor called after the copy of parameters?

Tags: groovy, constructor

I have this code in Groovy:

```
class Person {
    def age
    Person () {
        println age // null
    }
}

def p = new Person ([age: '29'])
println p.age // 29
```

I need to read age value in constructor, but it isn't setted yet.

How can I do this?

Note: I don't want to use a init() method and call manually every time, like

```
class Person {
    def age
    def init() {
        println age // now have 29
    }
}

def p = new Person ([age: '29'])
p.init()
println p.age // 29
```

Link to [GroovyConsole](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/480005).

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a constructor like this:

```
class Person {
    def age

    Person(Map map) {
        for (entry in map) {
            this."${entry.key}" = entry.value
        }
        println age
    }
}
```

If you're using groovy 1.8, take a look at the [`@TupleConstructor`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) annotation, which will automatically build a constructor like the one above, as well as a list based one.

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor
class Person {
    int age
}

p = new Person([age: 99])
assert p.age == 99
```